# Azure Custom Vision API predict_image invalid status code

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services

I am trying to connect my app to Azure's Custom Vision API using the predict_image method of the predictor object(as seen in their [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/custom-vision-service/python-tutorial-od#prerequisites)). However it is giving me the following error: "Operation returned an invalid status code 'Not Found' ".

Screenshots Attached: [Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbXwD.png) [Actual Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6at9.png)

Answer (score 0):

Is there a default iteration set for the project? If the prediction endpoint is called without specifying an iteration id then that implicitly falls back to using the default iteration. But if there is no default iteration set then the service will respond with a 404. There should be more detail available in the response body.